# Modelling a team manager through a membership table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have the following Rails models connecting teams and users:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :teams, through: :memberships
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users
end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I want to implement a team manager via the existing memberships table.
Would it be a better idea to have a foreign key in the teams table like this:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :manager_membership, class_name: 'Membership'
  has_one :manager, through: :manager_membership, source: :user
  # ...
end
```

Or would it be better to have an extra column (with unique index) on memberships like this:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :manager_membership, -> where { manager: true }, class_name: 'Membership'
  has_one :manager, through: :manager_membership, source: :user
  # ...
end
```

I wonder if having foreign keys going both ways from team to a membership and back is weird? Or maybe it doesn't make much difference either way?

Comment: A `Team` can have only one `Manager`, and a `User` (manager) can have many `Team`s, right? If yes, then the Team should have a `manager_id` referring to a User

Comment: Is a team's manager always a member of that team?

Comment: Yes a team can only have one manager (and a user can manage many teams). And yes the manager will always be a member.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, you should be able to use a [single table inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html) for both your users and managers. That would mean you get to use the same `membership` relationship on both models.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :teams, through: :memberships
end

class Manager < User
  # your code
end
```

You can now use `Manager` wherever needed, and add any validations directly on that model. Remember to add a `type` column to your `User` table if you decide to go this route.

EDIT

Looking at this again, you will need to have a separate table to keep the relationship between your Manager's `team and the actual team they manage clear. Your`team` should be something like:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, through: :memberships

  has_many :teams_managers
  has_many :managers, through: :teams_managers
end

class Manager < User
  has_many :teams_managers
  # note here we're aliasing for clarity and specifying a source
  has_many :managed_teams, through: :teams_managers, source: :team
end

# this is your association model for managers <-> teams
class TeamsManager < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :manager
  belongs_to :team
end

# so now you could call something like this
manager = Manager.find 1
manager.managed_teams =>[...]
manager.teams =>[...]
```

You'd have to make the corresponding migrations to instantiate your `TeamsManagers` table as well.

Comment: How does the team model side end up looking?

Comment: Appreciate your insight, but I'm trying to keep use the memberships table for manager identification, to avoid another relationship in the mix.